# How do I do the same thing as reference using typeglob in perl?

Tags: perl, reference, typeglob

```
$ref = \%hash;
$ref = \@hash;
```

How do I do the same thing as reference using **typeglob** in perl?

What's the exact steps perl takes to interpret `$$ref{key}`?

Comment: Your first question is (unwittingly, I assume) unrelated to your second. `$$ref{key}` is the same thing as `$ref->{key}`, which would only be the case in your first assignment, but having nothing to do with the symbol table entry for "hash", but more to do with the fact that you can save a reference to a hash.

Comment: `How do I do the same thing as reference using typeglob in perl?`  People have read various things into this question, but I can't make any sense of it.  Can you completely rephrase it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're asking how you get a reference to a type glob, it's just:

```
my $ref = \*symbol_name_here;
```

For a "literal name" of the symbol, (that is where you type in the exact name of the symbol), and not a variable. But, you *can* do this:

```
my $ref = Symbol::qualify_to_ref( $symbol_name );
```

for a variable symbol. However, the above works with `strict` and the easier one below doesn't:

```
my $ref = \*{$symbol_name};
```

One of the nice things about [`Symbol::qualify*`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Symbol), is that it handles package names as the second variable. So...

```
my $sref = Symbol::qualify_to_ref( $symbol_name, $some_other_package );
```

does the same thing as `\*{$some_other_package.'::'.$symbol_name}` and it works with `strict`.

Once you have the symbol ref, to get the slot, you have to deference the reference, so perl does not think you're trying to use it as a hash, like so.

```
my $href  = *{ $sref }{HASH};
my $code  = *{ $sref }{CODE};
my $arref = *{ $sref }{ARRAY};
my $io    = *{ $sref }{IO};
```

#### Another Take

I put your two ideas together in a different way. If you have a symbol table reference, you can get the `HASH` slot and that is a reference just like any other reference to a hash. So you can do the following.

Either

```
*hash{HASH}->{key}
```

Or

```
${ *hash{HASH} }{key}
```

will work. These are safer, though

```
( *hash{HASH} || {} )->{key};
${ *hash{HASH} || {} }{key};
```

If you want to do this not with a direct entry, but a reference into the table, you would do the following:

```
my $ref   = \*hash;
my $value = *{ $ref }{HASH} && *{ $ref }{HASH}->{key};
```

**NOTE:** `%hash` absolutely needs to be a package variable. Only package variables reside in the symbol table (so only subs and `@ISA` and Exporter variables tend to be in modern symbol tables). Lexical variables (those declared `my`) reside in the ["pad"](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PadWalker).

---

**UPDATE:**

- I have gotten away from using `Symbol` so much. Curiously, even though it is *core*, it seems *non-standard* in the way Perlers do--and *see*--things. Instead, I use the direct way in what I call "no-blocks", as localized as I can make them.

  ```
  # All I want is one symbol. 
  # Turn strict-refs off, get it, turn it back on.
  my $symb = do { no strict 'refs'; \*{$symbol_name} };
  ```

  OR

  ```
  {   no strict 'refs';
      *{$package_name.'::'.$symbol_name} = $sub_I_created;
      ... # more reckless symbol table mucking...
  }
  ```
- I almost always use the `*STDERR{IO}` idiom for a glob file handle reference. In modern Perl, these are usually *objects*.

  ```
  my $fh = *STDERR{IO};
  say blessed( $fh ); # IO::File
  $fh->say( 'Some stuff' );
  ```

Comment: what if `%hash` is defined as `my`?

Comment: @Je Rog, It's not in the symbol table, but the "pad". See [`PadWalker`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PadWalker) for a grounding.

Answer (score 10):

Use the `*foo{THING}` syntax, which is documented in the [Making References section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References) of the perlref documentation.

> A reference can be created by using a special syntax, lovingly known as the `*foo{THING}` syntax. `*foo{THING}` returns a reference to the THING slot in `*foo` (which is the symbol table entry which holds everything known as `foo`).
>
> ```
> $scalarref = *foo{SCALAR};
> $arrayref  = *ARGV{ARRAY};
> $hashref   = *ENV{HASH};
> $coderef   = *handler{CODE};
> $ioref     = *STDIN{IO};
> $globref   = *foo{GLOB};
> $formatref = *foo{FORMAT};
> ```

For example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

our %hash = (Ralph => "Kramden", Ed => "Norton");
our @hash = qw/ apple orange banana cherry kiwi /;

my $ref;

$ref = *hash{HASH};
print $ref->{Ed}, "\n";

$ref = *hash{ARRAY};
print $ref->[1], "\n";
```

Output:

```
Norton
orange
```

As for the second part of your question, adding

```
print $$ref{Ralph}, "\n";
```

after Ed produces the expected output. The compiler generates code for this line that goes through the following sequence:

1. Fetch the pad entry for `$ref`.
2. Get `$ref`'s thingie.
3. Look up the key in the hash from step 2.

But don't take my word for it. To cut down the volume of output, consider a similar two-liner:

```
my $ref = { Ralph => "Kramden" };
print $$ref{Ralph};
```

Running it with a perl compiled for debugging gets us

```
$ debugperl -Dtls ref 
[...]
(ref:1) nextstate
    =>  
(ref:2) pushmark
    =>  *  
(ref:2) padsv($ref)              # STEP 1
    =>  *  \HV()  
(ref:2) rv2hv                    # STEP 2
    =>  *  HV()  
(ref:2) const(PV("Ralph"\0))     # STEP 3a
    =>  *  HV()  PV("Ralph"\0)  
(ref:2) helem                    # STEP 3b
    =>  *  PV("Kramden"\0)  
(ref:2) print
    =>  SV_YES  
(ref:2) leave
[...]
```

Note that it's slightly different for globals.

I'm not sure what your larger intent is, but there are some important caveats. Note that a typeglob represents a *symbol table entry*, so you can't get at lexicals this way because they live in pads, not the symbol table. For example, say you insert `my @hash = ("splat");` just before the assignments to `$ref` in the code above. The result may surprise you.

```
$ ./prog 
"my" variable @hash masks earlier declaration in same scope at ./prog line 11.
Norton
orange
```

The behavior with respect to scalars may also be surprising.

> `*foo{THING}` returns `undef` if that particular THING hasn't been used yet, except in the case of scalars. `*foo{SCALAR}` returns a reference to an anonymous scalar if `$foo` hasn't been used yet. This might change in a future release.

Tell us what you're trying to do, and we'll be able to give you specific, useful suggestions.

Comment: this explains the case when array/hash is defined as `our`,what about when they're `my`?

Comment: @Je Rog Lexicals (declared with `my`) are covered in the caveats section of my answer. The short answer is you can't. What is the overall intent of the code where you want to hack on typeglobs?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do the exact same thing with typeglobs as you can do with references (for example lexical variables never involve a type glob). What do you want to achieve in the end?

As for `$$ref{key}`, perl proceeds as follows:

- the first $ tells it that a scalar is returned
- the presence of a variable after a sigil indicates that that variable must a reference
- the `{...}` indicates that `$ref` must be a hash reference

Comment: I thought reference is implemented on top of typeglob underneath.

Comment: Well, that's not correct. References are implemented as 'RV's (Reference Values), which are a specical case of the 'SV's (Scalar Values). See http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RURBAN/illguts-0.36/index-14.html for gory details.

Answer (score 1):

Perl is remarkably and famously experimental:

Try:

```
 perl -MO=Terse -e' $ref = \%hash; $ret = $$ref{key}'
```

or:

```
 perl -MO=Debug -e' $ref = \%hash; $ret = $$ref{key}'
```

and all will be revealed.  If you have a debugging Perl, you can even do:

```
 perl -Dt -e'$ref = \%hash; $ret = $$ref{key}'
```

Comment: well, there's quite a lot of it.  the extra flags will enable some perl debugging which should help you answer your question.